# Creating a sparse matrix

Tags: matrix, sparse-arrays

I would like to create the following sparse matrix

\begin{equation}
A = 
\begin{pmatrix}
a1+b1 t  & k-1 & 0 & \ldots &0 \\
a2^{2}+b2^{2} t  & a1+b1t  & k-2 & \ldots &0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\
ak-1^{k-1}+bk-1^{k-1} t  & ak-2^{k-2}+bk-2^{k-2} t  & ak-3^{k-3}+bk-3^{k-3} t & \ldots & 1\\
ak^{k}+bk^{k} t  & ak-1^{k-1}+bk-1^{k-1} t  & ak-2^{k-2}+bk-2^{k-2} t &  \ldots & a1+b1t \\
\end{pmatrix},
\end{equation}
where $ai$, $bi$ and $t$ are variables.
My current script reads

```
mat[a_, b_, t_, n_] := Module[{tmp = 0, tmp2 = 0}, Do[
   tmp = SparseArray[{Band[{m, 1}] -> a^m + b^m  t}, {n, n}];
   tmp2 = tmp + tmp2;
   , {m, 1, n}]; tmp2]
```

which keeps $a^{i}+b^{i} t$ on the $i$th lower diagonal of the matrix. How can I introduce variables `ai` and `bi` such that I ensure having $ai^{i}+bi^{i} t$ on these diagonals instead of $a^{i}+b^{i} t$?

Comment: You may want to consider `a[i]` instead of `ai`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note that your current code does not create the element (k-i). To change a to ai and b to bi in your current script you can use "Symbol" like:

```
mat[a_, b_, t_, n_] := 
 Module[{tmp = 0, tmp2 = 0}, 
  Do[tmp = 
    SparseArray[{Band[{m, 1}] -> 
       Symbol["a" <> ToString[m]]^m + 
        Symbol["b" <> ToString[m]]^m   t}, {n, n}];
   tmp2 = tmp + tmp2;, {m, 1, n}]; tmp2]
```

[image]

**Addendum**

To add he k-1 element:

```
mat[a_, b_, t_, n_] := 
 Module[{tmp = 0, tmp2 = 0}, 
  Do[tmp = 
    SparseArray[{Band[{m, 1}] -> 
       Symbol["a" <> ToString[m]]^m + 
        Symbol["b" <> ToString[m]]^m   t}, {n, n}];
   tmp2 = tmp + tmp2;, {m, 1, n}];
   tmp2 + SparseArray[{{i_, j_} /; j - i == 1 -> i - 1}, {n, n}]]

mat[a, b, t, 4] // MatrixForm
```

[image]

Comment: Great! Thank you very much.

Comment: Look at the "Addendum"

Comment: Thanks for the update. Replacing `i-1` with `n-i` makes the matrix correct.

Answer (score 4):

```
sa[a_, b_, t_, n_] := SparseArray[Prepend[Band[{1, 2}] -> Range[0, n - 2]] @
 Table[Band[{m, 1}] -> 
    Symbol["a"<>ToString[m]]^m + Symbol["b"<>ToString[m]]^m t,{m, n}],
 {n, n}]

MatrixForm @ sa[a, b, t, 5]
```

[image]

Comment: ,(+1) thank you for your response. It is simpler than my script.